# How can I restrict user from accessing some specific urls?

Tags: django, django-views

I have created a view which allow user to delete a specific Booking provided with id but I dont want other user except the user associated with the Booking object to delete it. How I can restrict user to access urls which delete booking they not own.

The urls:

```
path('manage/', views.ManageView, name='manage'),
path('manage/delete_booking/(?P<pk>\d+)', views.delete_booking, name='delete_booking'),
```

The views:

```
@login_required
def delete_booking(request, pk):
    booking = Booking.objects.get(pk=pk)
    booking.delete()
    return redirect('manage')


@login_required
def ManageView(request):
    bookings = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = { 
    'user': request.user,
    'bookings': bookings
    }

    return render(request, 'timetable/manage.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<div class="w3-content">
  <div class="w3-third w3-padding w3-center">
    <h4 class="bg-color">Infomation</h4>
    <p>Student ID: {{ user.profile.student_id }}</p>
    <p>Full name: {{ user.last_name }} {{ user.first_name }}</p>
</div>
<div class="w3-two w3-padding w3-center">
    <h4 class="bg-color">Booking</h4>
    {% if not bookings.exists %}
        <p>You don't have any booking</p>
    {% else %}
    {% for booking in bookings %}
        <p>{{ booking.room }} {{ booking.date }} {{ booking.lesson.number }} <a href="{% url 'delete_booking' booking.pk %}">Delete</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **check in the view**, for example:

```
@login_required
def delete_booking(request, pk):
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=pk, user=request.user)
    booking.delete()
    return redirect('manage')
```

Here it will raise a 404 error (not found) in case it can not find an object with that `pk`, or the user is not `request.user`.

You can also check:

```
@login_required
def delete_booking(request, pk):
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=pk)
    if booking.user_id != request.user.id:
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
    booking.delete()
    return redirect('manage')
```

This will return a 401 error (not authorized).

Both methods have its merits. For example by raising a 401, you give a "hint" that there exists an object with this `pk`. A malicious user could then try to access (view, alter, or delete) the object through another way. On the other hand a 401 describes better what the problem is: the user can not view/update/change the object. The frontend can give a more informative message. For example if a certain administrator has not enough rights to handle a certain object.

> **Note**: usually only POST, PATCH, PUT, and DELETE methods should have side-effects. So you might want to omit the `request.method == 'GET'` case as well. Robots like search engines typically "assume" that GET requests are safe (well actually they should be safe). So by not checking the method, a search engine could "trigger" removal, updates, etc.